# Jenkins QA Deployment

Tags: jenkins, deployment, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I have a QA Jenkins Job and I am trying to set Cronjob in QA Jenkins Job. So whenever the Cronjob triggers the QA Jenkins job, it need to take lastsuccessfulbuild artifact of Dev Jenkins Job. Is there any way we could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the DEV job you need to archive the artifacts you want to transfer (post build operation -> archive artifacts).

In the QA job you need to [Copy Artifacts from a different job](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin), select your DEV job name, and select latest successful.

That's as simple as that.